# python subprocess.call does not execute in if statement

Tags: python, shell, subprocess, execute

I have this block:

```
if data[0] == OUTPUT:
    pin,val = ord(data[0]),ord(data[1])
    if (pin == 1): #Turn Master Bedroom Light on
        process = subprocess.call(cmd1, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        print process
    elif (pin == 2): #Turn Master Bedroom Light off
        process = subprocess.call(cmd2, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        print process
    elif (pin == 3 or pin == 4): #Toggle garage door
        process = subprocess.call(cmd3, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        print process
    else:
        print "Invalid Pin"
```

where cmd1, cmd2 and cmd3 are shell script files that I'm trying to execute and OUTPUT is a predefined constant equaling 1. I know the block actually executes but it hangs with the subprocess.call statement.

When I run:

```
subprocess.call(cmd1, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

by itself in the python interpreter, it works just fine, but in my if-elif block it hangs. Any idea why? I am completely baffled... I am ignoring the value of val for now until I can get this to work.

Thanks in advance! I am fairly new to python so please be gentle :)

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation for subprocess.call](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) states

> Do not use stdout=PIPE or stderr=PIPE with this function. As the pipes
>   are not being read in the current process, the child process may block
>   if it generates enough output to a pipe to fill up the OS pipe buffer.

Answer (score -1):

> OUTPUT is a predefined constant equaling 1

If `data[0] == 1`, your `ord()` calls would fail. You don't mention about that, so nothing alike happens.

If, as I suppose, `data` is probably a string or a `bytes()` or a unicode thing and `data[0] == '\x01'`, there are two possible cases:

Either `OUTPUT` is really `== 1`, then the test for `data[0] == OUTPUT` fails, as `'\x01' != 1`, and the whole stuff is skipped. This is the most probable scenario.

Or `OUTPUT == '\x01'`, then the whole stuff executes and your first `if` block is executed, but you tell us that doesn't happen.

A [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) would be helpful.

Comment: if `data[0]` equals `1`, `ord(data[0])` gives an error (`expected string of length 1, but int found`). If however, `data[0]` equals `"1"`, `ord(data[0])` equals `49`.

Comment: @ExP That's why I suppose that `data[0] == '\x01'`.

Comment: @glglgl my mistake it is 'OUTPUT = chr(1)'